# NextJS Multi-tenant app with different page routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, multi-tenant, nextjs-dynamic-routing

So, just an overview of how I want things to work first so you understand the problem I'm facing.

**NextJS** is acting as the frontend to a **multi-tenant SaaS** app with **Django** and **GraphQL** as the backend. Depending on whether they access the site at the main domain (eg "mysasssoftware.com") or whether they access at a subdomain or a customer (eg "tenant1.mysaassoftware.com" or "tenant1customdomain.com")

I'd like a different set of pages for if accessing on the main domain or a tenant domain. I have envisaged a project structure like:

```yaml
my-project/
    config/
    default.json
    development.json
    productiuon.json
  public/
  src/
    server.js
    assets/
      fonts/
      images/
      scss/
    components/
      dashboard/
      frontend/
    pages/
      saas/
        index.js
        ....
      tenants/
        index.js
        ....
```

So then if they access on the main domain they should pull pages from:

`src/pages/saas`

If they access on a tenant domain they should pull pages from:

`src/pages/tenants`

This is my current server.js:

```js
const { createServer } = require('http');
const { parse } = require('url');
const { join } = require('path');
const { existsSync } = require('fs');
const next = require('next');
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();
const config = require('config');
const path = require('path');
const { pathExists } = require('fs-extra');
const dynamic = require('next/dynamic');

async function handleRequest(req, res, pagePath, query) {
  const adjustedPagePath = pagePath === '/' ? '/index' : pagePath;

  const filePath = path.join(__dirname, `./pages${adjustedPagePath}.js`);
  const indexFilePath = path.join(__dirname, `./pages${adjustedPagePath}/index.js`);

  const fileExists = await pathExists(filePath);
  const indexFileExists = await pathExists(indexFilePath);

  if (fileExists || indexFileExists) {
    const targetPath = fileExists ? filePath : indexFilePath;

    const ComponentModule = dynamic(() => import(targetPath));

    let serverProps = {};
    if (ComponentModule.getServerProps) {
      serverProps = await ComponentModule.getServerProps({ req });
    }

    const finalQuery = { ...query, ...serverProps };
    await app.render(req, res, adjustedPagePath, finalQuery);
  } else {
    res.statusCode = 404;
    res.end('Not Found');
  }
}

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = createServer(async (req, res) => {
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
    const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl;

    console.log(`Incoming request: ${pathname}`);

    if (pathname.startsWith('/_next/')) {
      console.log('Serving Next.js internal file');
      handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
      return;
    }

    // Determine the API URL based on the incoming request domain
    const apiUrl = `https://${req.headers.host}/graphql/`;

    // Check if a file exists in the public folder
    const publicFilePath = join(__dirname, 'public', pathname);
    if (existsSync(publicFilePath)) {
      console.log(`Serving static file: ${publicFilePath}`);
      // Serve the file from the public folder
      app.serveStatic(req, res, publicFilePath);
    } else {
      // Check if the request comes from the main domain
      if (req.headers.host === config.get('mainDomain')) {
        await handleRequest(req, res, `/saas${pathname}`, { ...query, apiUrl });
      }
      // If the request comes from any other domain
      else {
        await handleRequest(req, res, `/tenants${pathname}`, { ...query, apiUrl });
      }
    }
  })
  
  server.listen(3000, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000');
  });
});
```

The logic to point at the pages directories is now working but I'm running into some issues:

Either I try to use normal imports and I get the errors:

```bash
frontend/src/pages/saas/index.js:1
import Head from 'next/head'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1203:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1293:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1096:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:935:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:112:18)
    at handleRequest (/home/user/coding/project/project-frontend/src/server.js:27:25)
    at async Server.<anonymous> (/home/user/coding/project/project-frontend/src/server.js:61:9)
```

Or I use dynamic imports like in `server.ks` example above and suffer this error:

```bash
export default function Home() {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1203:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1293:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1096:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:935:12)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:168:29)
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)
```

My index.js is below:

```js
const dynamic = require('next/dynamic')
const Head = dynamic(() => require('next/head'))
const Image = dynamic(() => require('next/image'))
const Inter = dynamic(() => require('next-inter'))
const styles = dynamic(() => require('../../styles/Home.module.css'))

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <main className={styles.main}>
        <div className={styles.description}>
          <p>
            Get started by editing&nbsp;
            <code className={styles.code}>src/pages/index.js</code>
          </p>
          <div>
            <a
              href="https://vercel.com?utm_source=create-next-app&utm_medium=default-template&utm_campaign=create-next-app"
              target="_blank"
              rel="noopener noreferrer"
            >
              By{' '}
              <Image
                src="/vercel.svg"
                alt="Vercel Logo"
                className={styles.vercelLogo}
                width={100}
                height={24}
                priority
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className={styles.center}>
          <Image
            className={styles.logo}
            src="/next.svg"
            alt="Next.js Logo"
            width={180}
            height={37}
            priority
          />
        </div>

        <div className={styles.grid}>
          <a
            href="https://nextjs.org/docs?utm_source=create-next-app&utm_medium=default-template&utm_campaign=create-next-app"
            className={styles.card}
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            <h2 className={inter.className}>
              Docs <span>-&gt;</span>
            </h2>
            <p className={inter.className}>
              Find in-depth information about Next.js features and&nbsp;API.
            </p>
          </a>

          <a
            href="https://nextjs.org/learn?utm_source=create-next-app&utm_medium=default-template&utm_campaign=create-next-app"
            className={styles.card}
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            <h2 className={inter.className}>
              Learn <span>-&gt;</span>
            </h2>
            <p className={inter.className}>
              Learn about Next.js in an interactive course with&nbsp;quizzes!
            </p>
          </a>

          <a
            href="https://vercel.com/templates?framework=next.js&utm_source=create-next-app&utm_medium=default-template&utm_campaign=create-next-app"
            className={styles.card}
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            <h2 className={inter.className}>
              Templates <span>-&gt;</span>
            </h2>
            <p className={inter.className}>
              Discover and deploy boilerplate example Next.js&nbsp;projects.
            </p>
          </a>

          <a
            href="https://vercel.com/new?utm_source=create-next-app&utm_medium=default-template&utm_campaign=create-next-app"
            className={styles.card}
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            <h2 className={inter.className}>
              Deploy <span>-&gt;</span>
            </h2>
            <p className={inter.className}>
              Instantly deploy your Next.js site to a shareable URL
              with&nbsp;Vercel.
            </p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  )
}
```

My `package.json` is:

```json
{
  "name": "project-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon src/server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node src/server.js",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.7.12",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "config": "^3.3.9",
    "eslint": "8.38.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.3.0",
    "fs-extra": "^11.1.1",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "next": "13.3.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.4",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.62.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22"
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated on how to achieve this.